# How to create a custom release task that executes a console application with arguments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-extensions

I've been staring and trying the tutorials on here for a while, but I just can't come up with a solution.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/?view=vsts

I want to create a custom release task that executes SomeImportTool.exe with some parameters.

Currently I use the Command Line task with the following

```
Display name: 
    Run SomeImportTool
Tool:
    $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/SomeImportTool/SomeImportTool.exe
Arguments:
    -f "$(XmlFile)" -c "$(ConnectionString)" -l "$(CultureCode)"
```

How do I create a Task.json that basically does this?

```
{
    "id": "{{taskguid}}",
    "name": "SomeImportTool",
    "friendlyName": "Run Some Resource Import Tool",
    "description": "Run Some Resource Import Tool",
    "helpMarkDown": "",
    "category": "Deploy",
    "visibility": [
        "Release"
    ],
    "author": "{{author}}",
    "version": {
        "Major": 0,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Patch": 0
    },
    "instanceNameFormat": "Echo $(SomeImportTool)",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "advanced",
            "displayName": "Advanced",
            "isExpanded": false
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [

        {
            "name": "XmlFile",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "XmlFile",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "File path to the resource file"
        },
        {
            "name": "CultureCode",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Culture Code",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "culture code"
        },
        {
            "name": "ConnectionString",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Connection String",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Connection string"
        }
    ],
    "execution": {
        "PowerShell3":{
            "target": "someApplication.exe",
            "platforms":[
                "windows"
            ],
            "workingDirectory" : "$(currentDirectory)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the source code of vsts-task [CmdLine](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CmdLineV2/task.json) or [AzurePowerShell](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV3/task.json) task:

```
{
    "name": "ScriptArguments",
    "type": "string",
    "label": "Script Arguments",
    "defaultValue": "",
    "visibleRule": "ScriptType = FilePath",
    "required": false,
    "properties": {
        "editorExtension": "ms.vss-services-azure.parameters-grid"
    },
    "helpMarkDown": "Additional parameters to pass to PowerShell.  Can be either ordinal or named parameters."
},
```